# Deciding on answer for question

Tags: discussion

I am relatively new to stack exchange, and asked this question yeaterday: [Can government be funded by only printing more money and not taxing anyone?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22805/funding-government-by-only-printing-more-money/22856#22856). 
With the great number of answers I received, am I supposed to pick and accept one of them?  Different answers bring different points into the question, so I feel it is too hard to just pick one.

Comment: Related but still not entirely satisfying: [How to deal with many good acceptable answers?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116/how-to-deal-with-many-good-acceptable-answers/118#118)

Comment: Hi Eric. I'm closing this as a duplicate of the question mentioned by DaaaahWhoosh, because that one is about the same problem and has several good suggestions (also make sure to read the comments to the answer!). If you feel that question doesn't adequately address your concerns, please [edit] your question to point out the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's any number of strategies you can use to pick an answer.  Two are listed below:

**Highest Votes**

Just reward whoever got the most upvotes on their answer.  Usually the upvotes indicate that the answer is most useful to whoever looked at your question.

**Most Useful**

Depending on what you plan to use the answer for, you might pick a question that offers a particularly interesting insight or perspective that you find useful.